# Proof that $d(n)=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n}\implies d(n)=1-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} +\ldots+\frac{1}{2n-1}- \frac{1}{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

In the first place, I wrote down the very first terms of $d(n)$ for $n=1, \ldots, 4$.

$$d(1)=\frac{1}2$$

$$d(2)=\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4}$$

$$d(3)=\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}5 + \frac{1}6$$

$$d(4)=\frac{1}5 + \frac{1}6 + \frac{1}7 +\frac{1}8$$

Then I subtracted $d(n)$ to $d(n+1)$ for all these values of $n$:

$$d(2)-d(1)= \frac{1}3 + \frac{1}4 - \frac{1}2$$

$$\ldots$$

In the end I got the following formula:

$$d(n)-d(n-1)=\frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}n.$$

Adding these terms telescopically, I got to:

$$d(n) - d(1) = \frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2},$$

where $d(1)$ cancels out in the RHS, since it's $\frac{1}2$, getting to the following:

$$d(n)= \frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}n,$$

which simplifies to:

$$d(n)= \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n}.$$

How to solve it from this point onwards?

Comment: Did you try induction over $n$ ?

Comment: For $n=3$ $$\left(\frac14+\frac15+\frac16\right)-\left(1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac18\right)=-\frac1{24}$$

Comment: @DumperDGarb It should be $-1/6$ and not $-1/8$. That will give you $0$.

Comment: @peter no i did not try induction over n........i kind of wanted to avoid solving by induction

Comment: @Gary Ok, but there's clearly a 1/2^n in the OP.

Comment: @MaximLazovsky I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @DumperDGarb a mistake from my side.....as in while communicating through comments

Comment: A direct proof: $\begin{aligned}[t]d(n)&=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1k\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k-2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{2k}\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k-2\sum_{k\text{ even},\,\leq2n}\frac1{k}\\&=\sum_{k\text{ odd},\,\leq2n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k\text{ even},\,\leq2n}\frac{1}{k}\end{aligned}$

Comment: @2'59'2 in the first line of your proof , why did we take the lower bound as n+1?

Comment: Downvoted as I don't know what the question is (it is ambiguous). And the question should be in the body of the question.

Comment: @MaximLazovsky - Your starting expression for $d(n)$ sums from $\frac 1{n+1}$ to $\frac 1{2n}$. That is *exactly* what $\displaystyle\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac 1k$ means.

Comment: @PaulSinclair ahh yes yess, i get it thanks